# R: Stacked Bar Plot Error When Manually Ordering X Axis Data (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Hi and thanks for your time in advance.

I have some data imported from an Excel spreadsheet of the form

```
    # A tibble: 3 x 5
  Question          `Very Unlikely` Unlikely Likely `Very Likely`
  <chr>                       <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl>         <dbl>
1 when you graduate              20       57     36             7
2 in 10 years                     0       12     68            40
3 in 20 years                     0        2     32            86
```

I wish to create a stacked bar plot using ggplot, whereby the x axis contains the variable 'Question' and a set of four stacked bars for each subsequent column (i.e. 'Very Unlikely', 'Unlikely'). The y axis should plot the numbered value for each corresponding question-answer pair. I have created this plot successfully, but the order of the bars on the x axis appears to be random - it is 'in 10 years','in 20 years','after you graduate'

I wish to order the sets of bars corresponding to each question in the following way: 'after you graduate', 'in 10 years', 'in 20 years'

I tried the following code:

```
Fig3_Subset <- melt(Fig3[,c('Question','Very Unlikely','Unlikely','Likely','Very Likely')],id.vars = 1)

Fig3 %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Question = factor(Question, 
                                    levels = c('in 10 years', 'when you graduate', 'in 20 years'))) %>%

ggplot(Fig3_Subset, mapping = aes(x = Question, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  ggtitle("How likely is it that you will be using AI in your work...") +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank()) + 
  labs(title = "How likely is it that you will be using AI in your work...", 
       y = "Count",
       fill = "Answer")
```

But it returns this error:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (3): fill and y
```

Is there a better solution to the one I am trying to employ? If not, then how do I address this error? I have looked into some of the solutions online but none seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick. You don't need to mutate the Question column into a factor but you can use the fct_inorder function from forcats to get the order you need! It automatically recognizes a character column and can convert it to a factor. "inorder" sets the factor levels based on the order they appear. You can also you fct_reorder to reorder factor levels by values in a different column.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(reshape2)

Fig3 <- tibble(Question = c("when you graduate", "in 10 years", "in 20 years"),
               `Very Unlikely` = c(20, 0, 0),
               Unlikely = c(57, 12, 2),
               Likely = c(36, 68, 32),
               `Very Likely` = c(7, 40, 86))

Fig3_Subset <- melt(Fig3[,c('Question','Very Unlikely','Unlikely','Likely','Very Likely')],id.vars = 1)

Fig3_Subset %>% 
  ggplot(Fig3_Subset, mapping = aes(x = fct_inorder(Question), y = value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), stat = "identity") +
  ggtitle("How likely is it that you will be using AI in your work...") +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank()) + 
  labs(title = "How likely is it that you will be using AI in your work...", 
       y = "Count",
       fill = "Answer")
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I was starting to wonder why R didn't have such a simple function to perform this task. This is a much cleaner version of what I was trying to do. Thanks for the explanation too - that makes sense